# Substituting variable in string variable

Tags: scala

In the following example, I need the variable `x2` end up with the value `my name is Paul` instead of `my name is $name`, is this possible?

```
scala> val name = "Paul"
name: String = Paul

scala> val xxx = s"my name is $name"
xxx: String = my name is Paul

scala> val x1 = "my name is $name"
x1: String = my name is $name

scala> val x2 = s"" + x1
x2: String = my name is $name
```

Comment: You want to do this only via string interpolation?

Comment: I just need to replace the variable in another instantiated variable

Comment: Then using old C style `format` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String interpolation isn't a good fit here since you want to format an existing string. You want to use C style format of a string:

```
println("my name is %s".format("paul"))
```

If you want (although I see no good reason to), you can use `StringContext` directly:

```
scala> val name = "paul"
name: String = paul

scala> StringContext("My name is ", "").s(name)
res1: String = My name is paul
```

Comment: I think OP is interested in a way of interpolating a non-interpolated string that was already instantiated...

Comment: @Yuval I achieved what you are showing in variable `xxx`, that's not what I need

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
scala> val x4 = "my name is %s"
x4: String = my name is %s

scala> x4.format("Paul")
res3: String = my name is Paul
```